# allow GET request to /graphql endpoint instead of POST

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, strapi, apollo-server

we're looking into Automatic persisted queries with Apollo and Strapi as we're facing slow response time from graphQL.
I set APQs very easily (thanks to this conversation in strapi forums: https://forum.strapi.io/t/caching-graphql-query-results-with-strapi/1407/4)

In our frontend Next.js application we're using urql (lightweight apollo client alternative) and there's an option to send GET requests with the query which we've enabled.

The reason we want to send GET requests to GraphQL instead of POST is we want to enable Cloudfront CDN caching as well and Cloudfront doesn't cache POST requests but only GET requests.

With urql, if we send POST request to graphQL with hash, everything works fine and data is returned but with the GET request, we get below output with 200 status code:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Forbidden access",
            "extensions": {
                "error": {
                    "name": "ForbiddenError",
                    "message": "Forbidden access",
                    "details": {}
                },
                "code": "FORBIDDEN"
            }
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "about": null
    }
}
```

Any help on how to resolve it will be appreciated.

Comment: Your backend probably does not allow GET requests.

Comment: @ThisaruG right, that's the thing but the question is about, how to enable/allow it in Strapi?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Dashboard Settings within your Strapi interface. From there, access the User and Permissions Plugin section and choose Roles. Within Roles, navigate to the Public role and assign the necessary permissions to the endpoints.

[Check This Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULRAE.png)